# How to get the all related data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

The columns are `Id`, `Name`, `GroupId`, `CreatedTime` and `UserId`.

`GroupId` is the foreign key which references to `Id` and can be zero or more.
what I want is to get all `UserId`'s to one `Id`.

Let me explain :

If `Id = 1001` I can get a row and get the `GroupId` in the row.
and it maybe 0  or not
If not get the row that `Id` = `GroupId` in the row `Id=1001`
if it is 0 then return all `UserId`s

`Id     Name     GroupId     CreatedTime     UserId`

`1      John        0          2021-11-05       5`

`2      Harry       1          2021-11-01       3`

`3      Jenny       1          2021-11-02       2`

`10     Allen       3          2021-11-02       1`

The Id=10 how to get the UserId of 1 2 5

Comment: update your question  add a  proper data sample and the expected  result as tabular text

Comment: MySQL5.x or MySQL8?

Comment: MySQL 8   @MatBailie